# Cannot identify problem when requesting musickitusertoken, curl requests also do not work

Tags: ios, swift, curl, apple-musickit

I am getting this error when requesting a user token with Music Kit:

Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=7 "(null)"
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x281e94a20 {Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "(null)"
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x281e965e0 {Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store, SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=401}}}}}

I also am getting a 401 error when sending a curl request with the correct code:

`curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340"`

I have searched around endlessly and cannot find a solution. I have tried changing the dev token many times, so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue. Here is my code:

```
    SKCloudServiceController.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        if status == .authorized {
                self.cloudServiceController.requestStorefrontCountryCode(completionHandler: { (response, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(response!, forKey: "MusicKitCountryCode")
                        print("Country code")
                        print(response)
                        self.cloudServiceController.requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken: musicKitDevToken) { (responseString, error) in
                            if error == nil {

                                self.updateServiceTokens(token: responseString!)

                                print("should complete")
                                completion(true)
                            } else {
                                print("there was an error fetching user token: \(error!)")
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("error fetchin storefront country code: \(error!)")
                    }
                    
                })
            } else {
                print("cloud service controller not authorized`")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since a 401 error means you have an unauthorized client, then you may have a bad token.

Comment: Any familiarity with generating these types of tokens? Am following everything on the Docs, still getting 401 error.

Comment: Got it working @CodeBender token was malformed. Thanks for your help